# Unable to access database after restore with SA user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please look at the below server and database user and its properties.
I can't access the database using SA user

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure your SA user has a default database set. If the field is empty, it will prevent login.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. While i am selecting database from "User mapping" , i am getting below error.    
Create failed for User 'sa'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
Cannot use the special principal 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15405)

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems like you're trying to map the sa login to a user in the database. You can't do that. But sa automatically has full privileges in all databases.